# Gaussian Process - The variance term in Kernel matrix is not reducing to 0 at the Location of the Data Point

Tags: gaussian-process, covariance-matrix, kernel-trick, bayesian-optimization

I am running a variance reduction experiment using GPy library and sampling using Bayesian optimization suggested location. I noticed that once the data at certain location is added to GP's data set, the variance of that data is still largely positive (minute decrease from its original variance!) when the objective function is 2d function. This makes Bayesian optimization getting stuck at some local optima!
The variance goes to 0 in GPy library for 1D function but using 2D function such as Branin Hoo, the variance does not go to 0 at the data point location. I am using Matern25 kernel. I also tried with Gaussian kernel i.e. RBF.

Could this be a bug in the library or it is to be expected?

Comment: One possible reason is the high noise variance. Can you share your code, please?

Comment: Yes, i shall make a minimal reproducible code and add the code here. For now I am not sure if it got to do with noise variance as it is very minute from the following snippet ```m=GPy.models.gp_regression.GPRegression(x,                                                     np.reshape(y, (len(y), 1)),                                                  kernel=GPy.kern.sde_Matern32(input_dim=2, variance=1., lengthscale=.01),normalizer=True)``` The noise variance is quite small compared to values. I even tried ```0.1``` noise variance. I think the problem lies in the way the optimization  (continued)

Comment: (continued) of kernel hyperparameters in GPy library. So if I do variance reduction experiment by supplying "pure variance" `$\sigma^2$ as acquisition function then the location that has been sampled should never be suggested again. But in this case it does suggest again.